# Strange Ruby group_by and select behavior

Tags: ruby, arrays, select, filter

I'm getting strange behavior when trying to `select` from a hash created with `group_by`:

When I run

```
all_records.group_by(&:opportunity).map{|foo| foo[1].length != 1 }.select{|x| x}
```

I get some elements back: `=> [true, true]`

Yet when I try and select, with the exact block I `map`ped:

```
all_records.group_by(&:opportunity).select{|foo| foo[1].length != 1 }
```

I get no results: `=> {}`

Just as a sanity check, it works as expected when i first convert the hash to an array with `sort`:

```
all_records.group_by(&:opportunity).sort.select{|foo| foo[1].length != 1 }.length
```

Result: `=> 2`

It's strange to me, because the first result indicates that the hash recognized the `foo[1]` command perfectly. What's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet you are doing a `Enumerable#map` on a hash, with a block that gets a single argument (why don't you unpack it?), and here you get a pair (as you expected). In the second snippet you are doing a `Hash#select` again with a single argument (and again you should unpack the key/value), but here you get only the key, not the pair (because of how the method is implemented, check the source code for details).

```
>> {a: 1, b: 2}.map { |x| p x }
[:a, 1]
[:b, 2]
>> {a: 1, b: 2}.select { |x| p x }
:a
:b
```

If you go to the docs for [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select), you'll see it explicitly requires unpacked arguments. Conclusion: always unpack the key/value when iterating hashes with any method:

```
records.group_by(&:opportunity).select { |key, values| values.length > 1 }
```